# How to write text on image with tcpdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I want to generate dynvouchers pdf with tcpdf. I can get right pdf without username and password. This is my code :

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<table><tr>';
for ($a = 1; $a <= 5; $a++) {

    $html .= '
    <td>
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 320px;background-image:url(Voucher5.png)">
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <table  style="height: 20px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;" width="300">
        <tr>
        <td width="160">'.$username.'</td>
        <td width="160">'.$password.'</td>
        </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
    </td>';
if($a%2==0){
    $html.='</tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr>';
}
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf_file_name = 'custom_header_footer.pdf';
$pdf->Output($pdf_file_name, 'I');
```

I want pdf pages like this .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

TCPDF limited support for css attributes. `background-image`  Not supported by TCPDF. You can use `background-color` property instead of `background-image`.

Refer: [TCPDF - adding a background to a table cell or div that shows on PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451779/tcpdf-adding-a-background-to-a-table-cell-or-div-that-shows-on-pdf)

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"><tr>';
for ($a = 1; $a <= 5; $a++) {
   $html .= '
   <td>
   <div style="background-color:blue; color:#fff; text-align: center;">
   <br><br><br><br>
     <table border="1" >
     <tr>
       <td width="100">'.$username.'</td>
       <td width="100">'.$password.'</td>
     </tr>
     </table>     
  </div>
 </td>';
 if($a%2==0){
 $html.= '</tr><tr>';
 }
}
$pdf->writeHTML( $html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf_file_name = 'custom_header_footer.pdf';
$pdf->Output($pdf_file_name, 'I');
```

Comment: I need background image or write text on image

Comment: with tcpdf you can't. My suggetion is,  use domPdf. more information: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_009/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your username/password values are coming from, this could be from a database query or file, etc. So you need to include that in your code to set the username/password data.

However, the way you are concatenating strings and PHP variables is incorrect.
Instead of using `<td width="160">'$username'</td>` you should use DOT characters to correctly concatenate your php-variables in the HTML(that is a string) using this manner:

```
<td width="160">' . $username . '</td>
```

Hope that helps you on your way.

Comment: Username an password will generate random. I want to show sample usage for me , If i done this work i will add username and password to my sql table. I have done insert username and password randomly. This is sample usage , i write 5 iteration for this .